# Visa Application Confirmation Number and Barcode Number in Appointment Confirmation are different. Do I need to reschedule another appointment?

Tags: visas, usa

This is how it happened:

- I completed Visa Application, got a confirmation number.
- I scheduled an appointment with the US Embassy. I got a confirmation with a barcode which is the same as Visa Application confirmation number.
- Recognized I filled some fields wrong in the Visa Application, corrected them and got another confirmation number which is now different from the barcode in the appointment confirmation.

Do I need to cancel the appointment and reschedule a new one?

Comment: Which US Embassy are you making an appointment with? Many of them use different booking systems, which may change the answer.

Comment: Please can someone help me in answering this question. I'm yet to go for an interview, and my interview is scheduled for october.the barcode number on my schedule appointment and the barcode on my printed confirmation page are different. Please what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to make a new appointment. Also, just an FYI, depending on the visa category you apply for - if there is misrepresentation of facts of any kind in the DS 160, and the VO in the consulate evaluates it to be a misrepresentation, you may face a ban on entering the US.